# Char** + inputting " " characters

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I currently am trying to solve a maze algorithm, but I'm having starting because I cannot seem to grab " " characters from the user.  I don't know the size of the maze until the user inputs a size, so I have a char** setup for a 2d array.  I found I cannot use cin for a obtaining " ", so I thought to use either cin.get, or cin.getline, and can't seem to utilize them properly.  This is the problematic section of my code:

```
int main(){
    int size_x;
    int size_y;
    char** array;


    cin >> size_x >> size_y;
    array = new char* [size_y];
    for(int i=0; i < size_y; i++)
            array[i] = new char[size_x];

    //This part seems to not work properly
    for(int i = 0; i < size_y; i++){
            for(int k = 0; k < size_x; k++){
                    array[i][k] = cin.get();
            }
    }
```

After I input 1 character, the remaining characters are taken as nothing and the program skips past the remaining portion of this.  This is the output for when I input a 1 for size_x and 4 for size_y and I put a 1234 for the input afterwards:

```
1
2
3
done
```

I'm probably just doing something really silly, but I can't figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For cin.get(), you get only one of those characters, and it is treated as a char.  Modify array[i][k] = cin.get(); to cin>>array[i][k]  works.

Comment: When I do cin >> array[i][k] it does not allow me to input " " characters.  I need those spaces, too.

Comment: Try cin>>noskipws>>array[i][k];

Answer (score 0):

You could use getchar() instead

Comment: Doesn't getchar() return an int? Would I have to change my char** array to an int** array then?